# looping through string object dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

So, im successfully looping through a  dictionary of JSON data, for anything that has a single value as such:

```
var jsonData = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtMessage")).Text;

var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string,object> item in obj)
{
    var key = item.Key;
    var value = item.Value;
    if (key == "PercentageMatch")
    {
        ((Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblMatchedPercent")).Text =     
        value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I know need to add some additional code to read in the values of AKA's, which I know is more than up value, sometimes 10.

So, my code would look something similar to this:

```
var jsonData = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtMessage")).Text;

var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string,object> item in obj)
{
    var key = item.Key;
    var value = item.Value;
    if (key == "PercentageMatch")
    {
        ((Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblMatchedPercent")).Text = 
         value.ToString();
    }
    if (key == "MatchedPerson")
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,object> aka in item)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but this isn't obviously correct.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a `json` example for your case and tell us exactly which section your trying to extract or set ?

Comment: Orel, the data is striven, but i've uploaded a screen grab of what i need to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the value is supposed to be another dictionary, so you can do something like:

```
foreach(var aka in (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)value)
{
}
```

also note that looping through the pairs of a dictionary and matching on key is inefficient, you could use `TryGetValue` instead:

```
object person;
if(obj.TryGetValue("MatchedPerson", out person))
{
    foreach(var aka in (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)person);
}
```